# Xml element not found

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I'm trying to manipulate an XML file but I'm having problems.
At the moment, I'm trying to get the tag value highlighted below, but I'm not getting it.

XML File

```
<!-- language:xml -->
<cteProc versao="2.00" xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/cte">
    <CTe xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/cte">
        <infCte versao="2.00" Id="CTe35170208310367000113570010001828261272183608">
            <ide>
                <cUF>35</cUF>
                <cCT>27218360</cCT>
                <CFOP>5353</CFOP>
                <natOp>Prest. Serv. Transporte A Estab. Comercial</natOp>
                <forPag>2</forPag>
                <mod>57</mod>
                <serie>1</serie>
                <nCT>182826</nCT>
                <dhEmi>2017-02-13T08:57:27</dhEmi>
                <tpImp>1</tpImp>
                <tpEmis>1</tpEmis>
            </ide>
            <compl>
                <Entrega>
                    <semData>
                        <tpPer>0</tpPer>
                    </semData>
                    <semHora>
                        <tpHor>0</tpHor>
                    </semHora></Entrega>
                </compl>
                <vPrest>
                    <vTPrest>2440.00</vTPrest>
                    <vRec>2440.00</vRec>
                    <Comp>
                        <xNome>Frete</xNome>
                        <vComp>2147.20</vComp>
                    </Comp>
                </vPrest>
                <infCTeNorm>
                    <infCarga>
                        <vCarga>0.00</vCarga>
                        <proPred>jkfhmjhmh</proPred>
                        <infQ>
                            <cUnid>00</cUnid>
                            <tpMed>LITRAGEM</tpMed>
                            <qCarga>1000.0000</qCarga>
                        </infQ>
                    </infCarga>
                </infCTeNorm>
            </infCte>
            <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                <SignedInfo>
                    <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315" />
                    <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1" />
                    <Reference URI="#CTe35170208310367000113570010001828261272183608">
                        <Transforms>
                            <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" />
                            <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315" />
                        </Transforms>
                        <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
                        <DigestValue>VlX1bKhOHjQb5QCv6TliOoMFmwA=</DigestValue>
                    </Reference>
                </SignedInfo>
                <SignatureValue>xxxxxxxxxxxx</SignatureValue>
                <KeyInfo>
                    <X509Data><X509Certificate>xxxxxxxxxxxxxx</X509Certificate></X509Data>
                </KeyInfo>
            </Signature>
        </CTe>
        <protCTe versao="2.00">
            <infProt>
                <tpAmb>2</tpAmb>
                <verAplic>SP-CTe-22-12-2016</verAplic>
                **<chCTe>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</chCTe>**
                <dhRecbto>2017-02-13T09:09:08</dhRecbto>
                <nProt>135170007940102</nProt>
                <digVal>VlX1bKhOHjQb5QCv6TliOoMFmwA=</digVal>
                <cStat>100</cStat>
                <xMotivo>Autorizado o uso do CT-e</xMotivo>
            </infProt>
        </protCTe>
    </cteProc>
```

I'm trying to get the tag **"<**chCTe>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"**, but always return `null`.

Code

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("file_1.xml");
var c = from a in doc.Descendants("chCTe") select a;
```

Comment: Try googling default namespace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Parse(str);
XNamespace nsSys = "http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/cte";
string value = xDoc.Descendants(nsSys + "chCTe").FirstOrDefault()?.Value;
value.Dump();
```